# CMake флаг линковки

Tags: cmake

В проекте нужно использовать библиотеку `pthread`. Для этого нужно линковщику передать флаг `-lpthread`. Если я пишу свой MakeFile, то все работает, но в проекте я использую `cmake`. Как там указать этот флаг?
Я пробовал делать так

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -lpthread")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lpthread")

set(CMAKE_LDFLAGS "${CMAKE_LDFLAGS} -lpthread")
```

ни один из способов не подходит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для линковки с внешними библиотеками у `CMake` в файле `CMakeLists.txt` нужно указать параметр [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html). В данном случае будет что-то, подобное следующему:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC pthread)
```